# Can magnetic Susceptibility be complex?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, magnetic-moment

Can the magnetic susceptibility of a material be complex? Then what will that complex term represents? does it represent any kind of energy loss in the material?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AC Magnetic Susceptibility](https://qdusa.com/siteDocs/appNotes/1078-201.pdf), has a real and an imaginary part.

> The imaginary component, χ" , indicates dissipative processes in the sample.
> In conductive samples, the dissipation is due to eddy currents.
> Relaxation and irreversibility in spin-glasses give rise to a nonzero χ" . In ferromagnets, a nonzero imaginary susceptibility
> can indicate irreversible domain wall movement or absorption
> due to a permanent moment. Also, both χ' and χ" are very
> sensitive to thermodynamic phase changes, and are often used
> to measure transition temperatures. AC magnetometry allows
> one to probe all of these interesting phenomena.

In some cases it is also called the dynamic susceptibility when at higher frequencies. Usually you are applying a AC magnetic field on top of a DC field as a function of frequency and measuring both amplitude and phase shift with respect to the driving frequency so you can represent the signal as a complex number.